# Jquery hide Div with anchor text when bottom page section is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a auto scroll function, there is a static arrow which lets the user scroll to the next section of the page. When the user reaches the "contact" section (the last page), I would like the arrow to hide as there is no other page to scroll down to.

## Update -

Currently the navigation arrow dissapears on the last page but it also dissapears on the about and intro sections too.. How can i fix

## Jquery - Updated v3

```
$(function() {

$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');


    event.preventDefault();


    });


 });


function nextSection()
{

var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
$('#section-navigator a').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));

    if (refElement.position().top > scrollPos) {
               var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

    event.preventDefault();
        location.hash = "";
        location.hash = currLink.attr("href"); 

        if ($($anchor.attr('href')).attr('id') == "contact") {
$("div.page-scroll").hide();
  }

        return false;


       }


     });
 }
```

## HTML

```
<div class="page-scroll">
    <img class="arrow-down page-scroll-btn" src="img/arrow_dark.png" onclick="nextSection()" />
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you print the $($anchor.attr('href')) value on your console to check whether execution is entering the 'if' block or not? And if it is then what's the value of $($anchor.attr('href'))? Do that. Because most probably, your execution is not entering the 'if' block and executing the 'else' block. Add a statement like console.log("else block") inside the else block to see if it enters the if block or else block.

Comment: You should use  condition of `if` inside brackets like `if($($anchor.attr('href')) == "contact")`

Comment: mm so weird if i put -   if($($anchor.attr('href')) == "contact") {
                
                $("a.page-scroll").hide();
                }

it still doesnt work... should i be putting this inside the next function or the first function

Comment: this is because `$anchor` has nothing because it's outside the `nextSection()`

Comment: you should use this `if($('#selector_name').attr('href')) == "contact")`

Comment: I have tried both your suggestions Poonam but still no luck... I have updated the code

Comment: Can you make a working demo for us to look at? https://jsfiddle.net is a good place to do this.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments guys I will create a Js fiddle first thing in the morning as its midnight and i have been at it for over 10 hours. Really appreciate all help

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of things you use the links as the id for the next selector so you should be using `#contact` in your if.

Also, you have closed the if bracket `)` in the wrong place

```
if ($anchor.attr('href') == "#contact") {
}
```

If you want to compare it to the target divs id, then you need to do something like this:

```
if ($($anchor.attr('href')).attr('id') == "contact") {
    $("div.page-scroll").hide();
}
```

But this would seem like extra processing to get the same result

**Update**

Given all your edits - none of them really helpful as they don't create an MCVE - and we seem to be moving further and further away from the original question. I would do the following:

Get rid of that jquery onclick binding function at the top of your jQuery as you are manually binding in the html, the change your next section function to:

```js
function nextSection() {

  var currentPos = $(document).scrollTop();

  $('#section-navigator a').each(function() {
    var currLinkHash = $(this).attr("href");
    var refElement = $(currLinkHash);

    if (refElement.offset().top > scrollPos) { // change this to offset

      $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: refElement.offset().top    // just use refElement
      }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

      location.hash = "";
      location.hash = currLinkHash;

      if (refElement.attr('id') == "contact") {  // hide the scroller if the id is contact
        $("div.page-scroll").hide();   
      }

      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: @user1673498 Sorry, see edit, just noticed you had an extra `$` in there

Comment: your page scroll is a div - not an anchor!

Comment: I see...but that If statement would go under the first function and not the next section function right?

Comment: ok now its hiding the arrow but in all places. I will update the code again. Thanks Pete for the help

Comment: sorry, without an [MCVE], I really can't tell what you are doing wrong.  To start with though I son't see the point in the top function at all as you are binding a click (or not as it turns out) to something that holds an element that already has a click even bound to it

Comment: Thanks for all your help peter im currently in asia and its approaching midnight so i will create a Jsfiddle tomorrow as i have been coding for 12 hours straight - really appreciate all the help